# Active Directory Searching on Mac OS with .Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, active-directory, visual-studio-mac

I have recently moved from a Windows machine to a Mac and developing in ASP.Net Core.

I currently use the following code when testing on the Windows machine to look up users :

```
User LookupAdUser(String logon)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(logon))
            return null;

        User user = null;
        string domain = Environment.UserDomainName;
        PrincipalContext ctx = null;

        try
        {
            int index = logon.IndexOf(@"\");
            if (index > 0)
            {
                // a domain has been specified so get information from that domain
                domain = logon.Substring(0, index);
                logon = logon.Substring(index + 1);
                ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
            }
            else
            {
                ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
            }

            UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, logon);
            if (principal != null)
            {
                user = new User
                {
                    Logon = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}", domain, logon),
                    Email = principal.EmailAddress,
                    UserName = principal.EmailAddress,
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    Active = true
                };
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Logger.Error(string.Format("Failed to lookup the user ({0}) in AD...creating an empty User object", logon), ex);
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ctx != null)
                ctx.Dispose();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

When moving to the Macbook and testing the same code I get the error :

```
Exception thrown: 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
```

Is there any work around to this for the mac os to still tap into the active directory? or is just this not possible on mac?

Comment: You can't use `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll` on Mac OS, to the best of my knowledge! You should check other libraries available for Directory Access like NovellDirectory, etc.